# React eslint error missing in props validation on for the word "props"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, react-props

I have the code below:

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import myPic from "./pics/John_Smith.jpg";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
                <div className="App-Modal">
                    <p className="App-Modal-Text">5 Birthdays today</p>
                    {/* <BirthdayCard job="Developer"/> */}
                    <BirthdayCard />
                </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

const BirthdayCard = (props) => {
    console.log(props);
    return <article className="BArticle">
        <Image></Image>
        <Text></Text>
        <p>{props.job}</p>
    </article>

};

const Image = () => (
    <img src={myPic} alt="" />
 );

const Text = () => {
    return <article className="BText">
        <Name></Name>
        <Age></Age>
    </article>
}

const Name = () => (
    <h5>John Smith</h5>
)

const Age = () => (
    <p>30 years</p>
)

export default App;
```

I am getting the error; "job" is missing in props validation  react/prop-types, but this ONLY happens if I use the word "props" as a parameter. If I change it to anything else even "prop", the error goes away. Does anyone know why this is and how to fix it to be able to use "props" as a parameter?

Comment: Consider doing what the linter error says?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prop validations is a way of typechecking the props that a component recieves.

For instance, in the case of `BirthdayCard` you could do something like:

```js
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

BirthdayCard.propTypes = {
  job: PropTypes.string
};
```

So whenever you use `BirthdayCard` and pass the prop job with a type other than string you will get a console error warning you that the type should be string.

```
// This throws a console error
<BirthdayCard job={1} />

// This does not throw any error
<BirthdayCard job="programmer" />
```

If you are not going to be defining prop types you might want to disable this warning.

As of why it only throws the warning when the name is `props`, I have no clue. Maybe because it's a convention to use the name `props`.

Side note. You can use object deconstruction to clean your component definitions a little bit.

```js
const BirthdayCard = ({ job }) => {
    return <article className="BArticle">
        <Image></Image>
        <Text></Text>
        <p>{job}</p>
    </article>
};
```

Comment: Thanks much. This worked. I am curious as to why it only works when you use the word "props" as parameter and not any other word. Do you know why that is? ( I am assuming the need for props validation is to ensure that values of the wrong type are not passed into a function. )